# What's the VS Code hotkey for opening recent workspaces?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When Visual Studio Code opens, it shows a Welcome screen with, among other things, a list of recent workspaces:

[image: Recent items on Welcome screen]

If I click `More...` at the bottom of that list, a dropdown opens with a longer list of recent projects to choose from.

Is there a hotkey (or hotkey-bindable command) to bring down that list, without having to go via the welcome screen?

Comment: `Ctrl + R` should do it.

Comment: @RamizWachtler Doesn't on my machine. Do you know what the command is called?

Comment: Running that command opens a file open dialog, which is not what I'm after. There _is_ a command `Open Recent...` (`workbench.action.openRecent`) which seems to be bound to `Ctrl+R` in the default key bindings, but it doesn't trigger on my machine... :/

Comment: Adding the exact same config to my user-defined keybindings seems to help, though. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thanks, Tomas! I was looking for a command `Open recent workspace` or something similar the whole time and didn't expect `File: Open Recent…` (= `workbench.action.openRecent`) to also show recent workspaces…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ramiz seems to have the right answer in the comments.  I wonder if you have custom key bindings setup and/or adjusted this somehow without realizing.  Suggesting this as you seem to know how to do this.
You can go to the help menu and look for the Keyboard Shortcuts reference (Ctrl+k+r) or look https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf for the default.